# SQL table with "list" entry vs SQL table with a row for each entry

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have a `Sqlite` table where each row is the form of:

```
value, "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j", value3, value4
```

Where my queries look for a pairing of value, `%b%` using `LIKE`. Is it more efficient in terms of query time to instead have a table where each row is a permutation:

```
value, a, value3, value4
...
value, j, value3, value4
```

So that my queries are now value,b using the = operator this time.

As a note, the use case I'm interested in has ~10,000 rows currently where each "list" element has on average 8 entries. I tagged both `Sqlite` and `MySQL` because I have a similar problem for both a db with `MySQL` and `Sqlite`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where my queries look for a pairing of value, %b% using LIKE. Is it
>   more efficient in terms of query time to instead have a table where
>   each row is a permutation:

Most definitely. Because LIKE '%something%' type queries [cannot use indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html). So you look ups are going to be very slow. If that's not enough you are using pretty much an RDBMS anti pattern. more details here: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574)

once you break up your 'CSV' column into separate columns, you can take it still further by normalizing the database.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by normalize the database?

Comment: Bit too broad for a comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization