# CSV data is storing in same column in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I am trying to insert CSV file data into my database table using php . But my CSV 2 column data is storing in same column in database .

here is my database

[image: database]

here is my CSV data

[image: csv data]

Here is my PHP code

```
?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
  $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  $handle = fopen($file, "r");
  $c = 0;
  while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
  {
    $name = $filesop[0];
    $project = $filesop[1];

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytask (name, project) VALUES ('$name','$project')");
    $c = $c + 1;
  }

  if($sql){
  echo "You database has imported successfully. You have inserted ". $c ."recoreds";
  }else{
  echo "Sorry! There is some problem.";
  }

    }
 ?>
```

code refereed by [refrence](http://www.webtutorialspoint.com/php/how-to-import-excel-file-into-mysql-database-table-using-php-code/)

any help ..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL table with "list" entry vs SQL table with a row for each entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215624/sql-table-with-list-entry-vs-sql-table-with-a-row-for-each-entry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to give a value with comma seperated in CSV file .

example

coloumn1
name,project