# Fetching values stored as an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter-2

I have two tables namely `tbl_tools`and `tbl_tool_use`.
`tbl_tool_use` table looks like this

```
id  user_id     type    tool_id     quantity    start_date  end_date
30  27         engineer     5          2        2016-12-22  
31  gdf         team        8          2        2016-12-22  
32  26         engineer     7          2        2016-12-22  
33  26         engineer     7          2        2016-12-23  
34  hamsu       team        6          2        2016-12-22  
35  27        engineer      7,5        2,2      2016-12-22
```

`tbl_tools` table looks like this

```
id  name            quantity    available   type        
5   cutting player     5          5        engineer     
6   reflectors         2          2        team     
7   spanner            8          8        engineer     
8   tester             4          4        team
```

I want my result to be like this:

```
id  user_id     type       tool_id             quantity     start_date  end_date
30  27         engineer  cutting player            2        2016-12-22  
31  gdf         team     tester                    2        2016-12-22  
32  26         engineer  spanner                   2        2016-12-22  
33  26         engineer  spanner                   2        2016-12-23  
34  hamsu       team     reflectors                2        2016-12-22  
35  27        engineer   cutting player,spanner    2,2      2016-12-22
```

but am getting like this

```
 id user_id     type       tool_id             quantity     start_date  end_date
30  27         engineer  cutting player            2        2016-12-22  
31  gdf         team     tester                    2        2016-12-22  
32  26         engineer  spanner                   2        2016-12-22  
33  26         engineer  spanner                   2        2016-12-23  
34  hamsu       team     reflectors                2        2016-12-22  
35  27        engineer   cutting player            2,2      2016-12-22
```

if i have selected more `tool_id`s then also only one value is showing.
here is the code i used,my view looks like this,i had shown only the affected parts in the code

```
<tbody>
    <?php $n=1;

        foreach($all_assign_tool_info as $row) {                              
            $t=explode(',',$row->tool_id);
            foreach($tools as $res) {
                foreach($t as $res1) {
                    if($res1==$res->id) {
                        $tool=$res->name;
                        //var_dump($tool);
                    }
                }
            }
        }                   

    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $tool ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }?>
</tbody>
```

this is my controller

```
public function assign_tool($id = NULL)
{

    $data['all_assign_tool_info'] = $this->Tool_model->get_permission('tbl_tool_use');
    $data['tools']=$this->Tool_model->view_tools(null,null);
    $data['subview'] = $this->load->view('admin/tool/assign_tool',$data, TRUE);
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $data); //page load
}
```

my model looks like this

```
public function view_tools($limit,$offset)
{
    $this->db->order_by('id','desc');
    $query=$this->db->get('tbl_tools',$limit,$offset);
    return $query->result();
}
```

please help me to solve my problem

here is the newly included code
 my `tbl_tool_use` table looks like this

```
id  user_id     type       tool_id     quantity    start_date  end_date
136  27         engineer    11,5,7      3,5,2      2016-12-22
```

that means  `tool_id` `11` is `3`,`5` is `5` and `7` is `2` respectively
but the result am getting like this `5` is `3`, `7` is `5` and `11` is `2`
 the result obtained is like as follows
*[Valid XHTML http://spdc.in/demo/spectra/spectra_tool.PNG](http://spdc.in/demo/spectra/spectra_tool.PNG).*

Comment: you shouldn't be doing this http://stackoverflow.com/a/41215681/267540

Comment: you have printed your  <tr>
                                <td><?= $tool ?></td>
                            </tr>
outside of the foreach loop. so only one value is showing

Comment: THREE foreach with three different variables? which one contains table data? print that variable and show us some amount of data

Comment: just place `<tr> <td><?= $tool ?></td> </tr>` inside foreach

Comment: @ Anant `foreach($all_assign_tool_info as $row)` contains the table data of `tbl_tool_use` and this one `foreach($tools as $res)` contains the table data `tbl_tools`

Comment: the logic is simple nothing but if the `tool_id` of  `tbl_tool_use` is same as `id` of  `tbl_tools` the output should come that means the name of the tool should be visible its correct if the tool_id contains only one value but not stored as an array

Comment: anybody have any idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do away with iterations in PHP and focus more on writing the correct SQL syntax to obtain your results. Look into `FIND_IN_SET` and `JOINS` to make this work. Essentially, what you want is to join the two tables on the comma separated values. I would rewrite your Codeigniter model in this manner:

```
public function view_tools($limit,$offset)
{
    $this->db->select('tu.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name ORDER BY t.id) as tool_id', FALSE);
    $this->db->from('tbl_tools t');
    $this->db->join('tbl_tools_use tu', 'FIND_IN_SET(t.id, tu.tool_id)', 'inner', FALSE);
    $this->db->group_by('tu.id');
    $this->db->order_by('tu.id','desc');
    $this->db->limit($limit);
    $this->db->offset($offset);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot,its working and i have a doubt can i get result from my previous code written

Comment: what do you mean by "_in the order of table_"?

Comment: if the order of `tool_id` is 11,7,5 the result am getting is in order of 5,7,11

Comment: i had added the detail in question please have a look

Comment: so if the order of `tbl_tool_use -> tool_id`is 11,7,5, then your results should 11,7,5 ? In other words you want the order to follow the order on the column?