# Using 'IN' clause for strings in Sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Hi I have table which have 2 column. `Name varchar(50)` and `RoleType Varchar(500)`.

I have data as below img in table.
[image]

Now I am passing `roletype` 2 and 4 as parameter and want to get all data which have `roletype` either 2 or 4 in `Roletype` column. For example, result for 2 and 4 `roletype` are Test a, Test d, Test c and Test e.

I try with below query but it is not working.

`SELECT * FROM Userinfo where Roletype in ('2', '4')`

Comment: the real problem here is that you have a table badly in need of a redesign http://stackoverflow.com/a/41215681/267540

Comment: break your comma separated id into rows ,in case if you don't want to redesign your table architecture ...then store that id's into temporary table and then perform operation on that temporary table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Split function to split comma-separated column value:

Split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
    FROM Split
)
```

Now update your query as below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Userinfo 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT Data 
              FROM [dbo].[fnSplit] (Roletype,',') 
              WHERE Data IN (2, 4) )
```

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Category

SELECT * 
FROM Category C 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM [dbo].[fnSplit] (Name, ',') 
              WHERE DATA IN ('test', 'test3'))
```

Initial:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below query for getting your desired output -

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Userinfo
WHERE
    Roletype = '2'
OR Roletype = '4';
```

Comment: Err!! This will return 0 rows as per given OP's given.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    [Userinfo]  AS  [ui]
CROSS APPLY
    (
    SELECT 
        [str] = [X].[C].[value]('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
    FROM 
        ( 
            SELECT 
                [X] = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' + REPLACE([ui].[roletype], ',', '</i><i>') + '</i>').query('.')
        )                   AS  [A] 
    CROSS APPLY 
        [X].[nodes]('i')    AS  [X]([C])
    )           AS  [s]         
WHERE 
    [s].[str] IN ('2', '4');
```

Answer (score 0):

Split solution from Sandip Patel is good.
Still, you can use LIKE if you want.

You can write something like

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Userinfo
WHERE
    Roletype LIKE '%,2,%'
OR Roletype LIKE '2,%'
OR Roletype LIKE '%,2' etc.
```